# Django Rest Framework 3 - Many to many with extra fields

Tags: python, django, model, django-rest-framework, serialization

I have a problem with the serializers on Django Rest Framework... first my models are:

```
class Transaction(Model):
type_choices = (
    (1, 'deposit'),
    (2, 'withdrawal')
)

status_choices = (
    (1, 'pending'),
    (2, 'made'),
    (3, 'canceled'),
    (4, 'completed')
)

name = CharField(null=True, blank=True,max_length=50,)
description = TextField(null=True, blank=True)
amount = FloatField()
type = IntegerField(choices=type_choices, )
status = IntegerField(choices=status_choices, )

client = ForeignKey(User, related_name='transaction_client', blank=True, null=True)

cards = ManyToManyField(Card, through='TransactionCard')

created_by = ForeignKey(User, related_name='transaction_created_by')
created_at = DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True, editable=False)
updated_by = ForeignKey(User, null=True, related_name='transaction_updated_by')
updated_at = DateTimeField(auto_now=True, editable=False)

class Meta:
    ordering = ('-created_at',)

def __str__(self):
    return self.name


class TransactionCard(Model):

transaction = ForeignKey(Transaction, related_name='transactioncard_transaction')
card = ForeignKey(Card, related_name='transactioncard_card')
amount = FloatField()

class Card(Model):
name = CharField(null=True, blank=True, max_length=100,)
description = TextField(null=True, blank=True,)
card_number = TextField(max_length=16, )
month_exp = IntegerField()
year_exp = IntegerField()
month_acq = IntegerField(null=True, blank=True,)
year_acq = IntegerField(null=True, blank=True, )

card_type = ForeignKey(CardType, related_name='cards_card_type')
provider = ForeignKey(Provider, related_name='cards_provider')

balance = FloatField()

active = BooleanField()

created_by = ForeignKey(User, related_name='cards_created_by')
created_at = DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True, editable=False)
updated_by = ForeignKey(User, null=True, related_name='cards_updated_by')
updated_at = DateTimeField(auto_now=True, editable=False)

class Meta:
    ordering = ('month_exp', 'year_exp',)

def __str__(self):
    return self.name
```

And my serializers are:

```
class TransactionCreateSerializer(ModelSerializer):
created_by = StringRelatedField()
updated_by = StringRelatedField()

class Meta:
    model = Transaction
    fields = [
        'id',
        'name',
        'description',
        'amount',
        'type',
        'status',
        'client',
        'cards',
        'created_by',
        'created_at',
        'updated_by',
        'updated_at'
    ]
    extra_kwargs = {
        'created_by': {
            'read_only': True
        },
        'updated_by': {
            'read_only': True
        }
    }

def create(self, validated_data):
    pprint(validated_data.pop('cards'))
    transaction = Transaction.objects.create(**validated_data)
    return transaction
```

My problem is when i will try to get validated_data.pop(cards) an error ocurrs and i don't know why.

**UPDATE**

The error it's:

```
pprint(validated_data.pop('cards))
KeyError: 'cards'
```

Comment: What is the error message?

Comment: The error its: pprint(validated_data.pop('cards))
KeyError: 'cards'

Comment: Is `validated_data` a list or a dict?
If it is a dict, you can get the card via validated_data['cards']

Comment: I tried that and i obtain the same error. My post request looks like:

{"name":"1","description":"1","type":"1","amount":1,"status":"1","client":2,"cards":[{"card":1,"amount":1}]}

Comment: It seems that 'cards' is not in your validated data. 
What happens if you print the complete ´validated_data´?

Comment: The output for the pprint validate_data is: {'amount': 1.0,
 'client': <User: cliente1>,
 'created_by': <User: User1>,
 'description': '1',
 'name': '1',
 'status': 1,
 'type': 1}

Comment: So there is no 'cards' in your validated_data.

Comment: Yep, that's the problem. How i can solve that?